# Different behavior between chain iterator in println! and from variable

Tags: rust

Why does the `println!` inlined code work in these examples and not the mutable variable?

I've predefined some constants:

```
static ASCII_LOWERCASE: [char; 26] = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
];
static ASCII_UPPERCASE: [char; 26] = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
];
static ASCII_NUMERIC: [char; 10] = [
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
];
static ASCII_SYMBOLS: [char; 33] = [
    '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-',
    '_', '+', '=', '~', '`', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', '\\',
    ':', ';', '"', '\'', '<', '>', ',', '.', '?', '/', ' ',
];
```

This works and prints 95 characters:

```
fn main() {
    for x in 0..95 {
        println!(
            "{}",
            ASCII_LOWERCASE
                .into_iter()
                .chain(ASCII_UPPERCASE.into_iter().chain(
                    ASCII_NUMERIC.into_iter().chain(
                        ASCII_SYMBOLS.into_iter(),
                    ),
                ))
                .nth(x)
                .unwrap()
        );
    }
}
```

This only prints 13 characters and panics:

```
fn main() {
    let mut ascii = ASCII_LOWERCASE.into_iter().chain(
        ASCII_UPPERCASE.into_iter().chain(
            ASCII_NUMERIC.into_iter().chain(
                ASCII_SYMBOLS.into_iter(),
            ),
        ),
    );

    for x in 0..95 {
        println!("{}", ascii.nth(x).unwrap());
    }
}
```

The failing output:

```
a
c
f
j
o
u
B
J
S
2
$
`
,
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /checkout/src/libcore/option.rs:335
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

The failing result is skipping most of the characters even though the same method is being called on the same iterator. Why is it doing that?

To get it to work the way I wanted I had to do:

```
fn main() {
    let ascii: Vec<&char> = ASCII_LOWERCASE
        .into_iter()
        .chain(ASCII_UPPERCASE.into_iter().chain(
            ASCII_NUMERIC.into_iter().chain(
                ASCII_SYMBOLS.into_iter(),
            ),
        ))
        .collect();

    for x in 0..95 {
        println!("{}", ascii[x]);
    }
}
```

Why does the failing version behave differently?

Comment: You don't  have to explicitly return `()`; I've removed that while reformatting the code to Rust standards and so that it fits in the SO interface better.

Comment: Also, I'd say that `a.chain(b).chain(c).chain(d)` is easier to read than the nested variant.

Comment: @Shepmaster no offense, but your code style choices I cringe at.  I never use four spaces when I can use two, and I never start lines with a period.  Also I prefer indentation in assignment to stay to the right of the equals or just have the whole thing dropped down via a backslash after the equals.  So I'm very uncomfortable with the way this question looks.  But thanks for the tip on `()`.

Comment: They aren't my coding styles *per se*. They are the standard style as codified in [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). I'm still not used to some of the recent changes myself, but I feel it's more important to confirm to the community's will to optimize code reading here in Stack Overflow so I run it on basically everything by default. You are always welcome to rollback or edit of course.

Answer (score 3):

This is, essentially, the difference between *an iterator* and *a collection*.

An iterator will *iterate* over a sequence of elements, *never yielding the same element twice* (although it may yield equal elements).

A collection is inert, and can be iterated over multiple times as long as you iterate *by reference* (using `into_iter` will generally consume the collection, emptying it).

---

What this means is that:

```
fn main() {
    for x in 0..95 {
        println!(
            "{}",
            ASCII_LOWERCASE
                .into_iter()
                .chain(ASCII_UPPERCASE.into_iter().chain(
                    ASCII_NUMERIC.into_iter().chain(
                        ASCII_SYMBOLS.into_iter(),
                    ),
                ))
                .nth(x)
                .unwrap()
        );
    }
}
```

Will, 95 times, create an iterator chain and reach for the `x` element. This has complexity **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**.

---

On the other hand:

```
fn main() {
    let mut ascii = ASCII_LOWERCASE.into_iter().chain(
        ASCII_UPPERCASE.into_iter().chain(
            ASCII_NUMERIC.into_iter().chain(
                ASCII_SYMBOLS.into_iter(),
            ),
        ),
    );

    for x in 0..95 {
        println!("{}", ascii.nth(x).unwrap());
    }
}
```

Will create an iterator once, then ask for the 0th element, then the 1st *remaining* element, then the 2nd *remaining* element.

The clue is in the `mut` keyword: the iterator is mutated (advances) each time you call `nth`, and you never "rewind it" in between loop iterations.

---

And finally:

```
fn main() {
    let ascii: Vec<&char> = ASCII_LOWERCASE
        .into_iter()
        .chain(ASCII_UPPERCASE.into_iter().chain(
            ASCII_NUMERIC.into_iter().chain(
                ASCII_SYMBOLS.into_iter(),
            ),
        ))
        .collect();

    for x in 0..95 {
        println!("{}", ascii[x]);
    }
}
```

Will create a *collection* once, and then index into that collection.

Note that you didn't need `mut` in front of the collection because it's not mutated.

---

The proper way, however, is to stop using indices. An iterator already iterates over a sequence of element, so you can just use that directly:

```
fn main() {
    let ascii = ASCII_LOWERCASE.iter().chain(
        ASCII_UPPERCASE.iter().chain(
            ASCII_NUMERIC.iter().chain(ASCII_SYMBOLS.iter())
        )
    );

    for x in ascii {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd still advocate for storing the iterator in a temporary variable. I hate the way multiline expressions look in a `for` expression. [An example of such](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=d334f88e1f35f73bde7767de7e37c26b&version=stable).

Comment: @Shepmaster: I'm ambivalent. I lack avoiding "residual" variables in scope, as accidentally reusing them is a sure way of introducing bugs, but... yeah... doesn't look too good as is here.

Comment: But how will you reuse the variable if the ownership of it has been transferred to the `for` loop? ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ah! Hadn't thought of that. Wish more languages had Affine Types :(

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The for loop is creating a new collection each time in the working example so `nth` is always referenced from the beginning.  Iterators are consumed via the `next` method so the failing version changes its reference point each `nth` call.

Comment: That is inaccurate: you were creating a new iterator chain in the first version, not a new collection. Since the obtained chain can only be consumed once, the second example fails once you try to take more than one element (because of `nth()`)